# How do I rotate the funnel chart 90 degrees in AmCharts?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using amCharts to create a Funnel Chart. The default demo provided by Amcharts is a vertical funnel.

What if I want to get a horizontal funnel chart using Amcharts?

Please see the code here.
http://jsfiddle.net/us8hgp6k/

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
     "type": "funnel",
     "theme": "none",
     "dataProvider": [{
         "title": "Website visits",
         "value": 300
     }, {
         "title": "Downloads",
         "value": 123
     }, {
         "title": "Requested prices",
         "value": 98
     }, {
         "title": "Contaced",
         "value": 72
     }, {
         "title": "Purchased",
         "value": 35
     }, {
         "title": "Asked for support",
         "value": 25
     }, {
         "title": "Purchased more",
         "value": 18
     }],
     "titleField": "title",
     "marginRight": 160,
     "marginLeft": 15,
     "labelPosition": "right",
     "funnelAlpha": 0.9,
     "valueField": "value",
     "startX": 0,
     "neckWidth": "40%",
     "startAlpha": 0,
     "outlineThickness":1,
     "neckHeight": "30%",
     "balloonText": "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>"    
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to create a horizontal funnel from a `funnel`-type chart. (The `rotate` property merely flips the chart upside down.)

But you can simulate a horizontal funnel by using a bar chart and overlaying a background on the bottom half ("negating") of the chart.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/Le8uncbo/light/).

Note these parts to recreate:

1. The `type` is `serial`. This creates a bar chart.
2. Each of the data values in `dataProvider` also has a negated value.
3. There are *two* graphs being drawn. The first graph draws the negation (the white space beneath the graph) using the negated values. The second graph draws the funnel using the positive values. Notice `fillToGraph` is set to `fromGraph`; this is the `id` property of the other graph.

According to the documentation, the [`fillToGraph`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#fillToGraph) property:

> You can set another graph here and if fillAlpha is >0, the area from this graph to fillToGraph will be filled (instead of filling the area to the X axis).